Decryption of LWE-based Inner-Product Fuctional Encryption of Agrawal-Libert-Stehle Crypto 2016
In below image, we have LWE-based inner-product functional encryption for short integers
[ALS'Crypto2016].

Is the encryption correct? Why do they get $\mu\in\{\color{red}{-K+1},\ldots,0,K+1\}$? When two vectors are non-negative, how their inner-product could be negative?
It's not the only paper that I have seen is written like this, so I'm asking here.
Besides that, Why they get "final error" in the decryption $<\lfloor\frac{q}{\color{red}4}\rfloor$? Why they don't get it $<\lfloor\frac{q}{\color{blue}2}\rfloor$ to get a correct "decoding mod q"
of message in this Regev-like cryptosystem.






Yes. The inner product must be non-negative, but the decryption algorithm may return a negative value. But, this can be easily fixed by returning $|\mu|$.
In Regev's cryptosystem, the message is either 0 or 1. That is why during encryption and decryption, we have $\lfloor q/2 \rfloor$ in the equations such that with high probability the decryption error $\lfloor q/4 \rfloor$. This bound on the error is crucial for decryption correctness. In the inner product case, observe that the message that is obtained after decryption is the inner product, which is a value from the set $\{0, 1, \dots, K-1\}$ of size $K$. So, we have $\lfloor q/K \rfloor$ in the equations, and the error must be at most $\frac{\lfloor q/K \rfloor}{2}$ to decrypt properly. To be precise, we have $$\mu' = \langle x, c_1\rangle - \langle z_x, c_0\rangle = \lfloor q/N \rfloor \langle x, y \rangle + \underbrace{\langle x, e_1 \rangle - \langle z_x, e_0\rangle}_{e=error}$$ By choosing the parameters appropriately, $e < \frac{\lfloor q/K \rfloor}{2}$ with high probability.


About the second part, It's correct that final error must be $<\lfloor\frac{q}{2K}\rfloor$. My question is:  Why do they get this upper bound $<\lfloor\frac{q}{4K}\rfloor$? As they state "Thanks to the choices of $\alpha$ and $q$, the latter upper bound is $\leq\lfloor\frac{q}{4K}\rfloor$"

@user1035648 Are you asking why the authors have mentioned $\lfloor \frac{q}{4K} \rfloor$ rather than $\lfloor \frac{q}{2K} \rfloor$? Or, are you asking for the calculations?

I'm asking why the authors have mentioned $\lfloor\frac{q}{4K}\rfloor$ rather than $\lfloor\frac{q}{2K}\rfloor$ ?

After skimming through the paper, I couldn't find a reason why the authors chose this. :( Nevertheless, both the values suffice for decryption correctness.
